# Can somehow a method from base class return child class?

Tags: c#

I'll give an example, so you can better understand what i mean:

```
public class Base
{
      public Base Common()
      {
          return this;
      }
}

public class XBase : Base
{

     public XBase XMethod()
     {
          return this;
     }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
var a = new XBase().Common().XMethod();
```

but this is not possible as `Common()` returns `Base`, and `XMethod()` is not defined in `Base`.

Is there any possible way i could acomplish this ?

I'm asking because i have a `BaseComponent`, and a lot of other `Components` that inherit this class, and i have to declare the common methods in each one, just to call `base.Method()` inside.

Thanks for your help.

PS: without using generics and specifying the child's type:

```
var a = new XBase().Common<XBase>().XMethod();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could make `Base` generic and use the [Curiously Repeating Template Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx):

```
public class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
      public T Common()
      {
          return (T)this;
      }
}

public class XBase : Base<XBase>
{
     public XBase XMethod()
     {
          return this;
     }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
var a = new XBase().Common().XMethod();
```

Comment: +1. Note that it has the same issue as the other answer - derived classes are not siblings because there is no common parent.

Comment: I'd note that you should avoid this pattern where you can. It's not very good, IMO.

Comment: Tim can you give more details?

Comment: @CristiPufu [Eric Lippert's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx), also linked from this answer, explains it in good detail, including why he discourages its use (though it can be useful). E.g. it can be misused, it's confusing to read, and it's an abuse of the type constraint mechanism because it doesn't tell you anything about how `Base` and `T` relate.

Answer (score 6):

Have `Base` be abstract and not implementing XMethod and have the classes overriding `XMethod` should do it I guess?

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
      public Base Common()
      {
          return this;
      }

     public abstract T XMethod();
}

public class XBase : Base<XBase>
{

     public override XBase XMethod()
     {
          return this;
     }
}
```

Comment: +1: Note that you need one more layer of inheritance (non-generic base) in this case, otherwise all "components" will be unrelated classes instead of siblings. (`Base<A>` and `Base<B>` don't have common parent if using `class Base<T> {}` as parent)

Comment: This is perfect for a builder type pattern.